# How to determine rss feed url of streaming audio android?

Tags: streaming, rss

**Main Question**:
While listening to streaming audio on my android device, how would I uncover the rss feed url the audio is coming from?

**My idea**:
Using a app similar to glasswire to see the address of the streaming audio while it's playing but I didn't have much luck. Possible I wasn't doing you correctly...

**More Details**:
I listen to a weekly show/podcast that is normally only available by using there app.

The problem is the app is horrible and the audio constantly stops, and you have to manually go back in restart that week's episode and find where you left off.

A couple of months ago while listening to an episode, they gave out the rss feed url for anyone that is having trouble with the app. I of course did not make note of it.

So I'm wondering how would I go about finding out the RSS feed url?

My initial idea was to use something like glasswire and and see if I can find the address while the audio is streaming on my device but have not had any luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the streaming app uses HTTPS you need a rooted device or a modified app to intercept HTTPS traffic to see the url. Some ways to monitor HTTPS traffic are e.g. summarized in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57570009/150978) on stackoverflow about network interception for Andorid.